# How can a NPC opponent be annoyed by barbarians in a barbarian-free game?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm playing a custom game of Civilization 6 with no barbarians. My opponent, Gilgamesh, just sent me the following complaint:

[image: Screenshot]

> Gilgamesh says:
>
> How can you let those Barbarians run amok so close to your home?
>
> (You have transgressed Gilgamesh's agenda, Civilized)

This is a barbarian-free game. What in the world is he complaining about?

I'm playing with no mods. I have the following DLC: Khmer & Indonesia; Nubia; Persia & Macedon; Australia; Poland; Vikings.

Comment: This is not directly civ related - but in several settings, peoples who see their own civilation as civilized will call people from other civilizations barbarians/infidels ...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [list of agendas](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_agendas_in_Civ6) gives 'Civilised' as 'likes Civs that clear Barbarian Outposts, dislikes ones that ignore them'.

It appears that the AI isn't sophisticated enough to realise that you're 'ignoring' barbarians because there aren't any around - he's just annoyed that you haven't dealt with any outposts recently.

If there are any neutral villages still around (the ones that give a random reward), try grabbing them - it's possible that will count towards his agenda. It's also possible that he'll settle down once borders start meeting and there's no neutral territory that barbs can spawn in.
Otherwise, he's just going to be permanently annoyed by your game settings.

On the bright side, getting upset over being denied a good brawl is entirely in-character for Gilgamesh...

Comment: Did a single Civ generation undergo basic playtesting?!

Comment: Basic playtesting yes but not comprehensive, the Devs seem surprised when people choose options they have made avaialbe to them like "No Barbs"!

Comment: It's also worth noting that, on top of comprehensive playtesting, there's the edge cases that come up - if this was a bug introduced not by immediate gameplay setup, within the first, say, 5 turns...running Soak Tests for every possible combination would be...difficult - especially if RNG is involved. What likely happened was there was supposed to be *a* prompt, and the validation usually looked like it was working fine for Barbarian checks - Unit Tests help here, but Integration Tests may be necessary at minimum to catch this interaction, and those are more complex. Soak Tests are longer.